# jquery bxslider slider with custom pager - auto play not adding active class to pager?

Tags: jquery

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/NXzcx/3/) to demonstrate my issue. http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/NXzcx/3/

**OVERVIEW**

I'm just starting to develop a website, and I want to use a versatile jQuery plugin to use for all my sliders and tickers on the site, instead of multiple jQuery plugins.

I've done a little searching around and stumbled across [jQuery bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) - the documentation looked good so I decided to give it ago.

I'm trying to create a similar slider to the one featured on the [google shopping](http://www.google.com/shopping) page. I can appreciate that this [jQuery bxslider plugin](http://bxslider.com/) might no be able to achieve the exact transitions between pagers.

**THE PROBLEM**

Please see my http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/NXzcx/3/ for reference.

As per the [google shopping](http://www.google.com/shopping) page example, I've managed to get the slideshow to automatically play, but it does not seem to add the `.page-active` class to current pager? ...and when you select the pager, it does not continue to automatically play? And the documentation does not seem to explain this.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

I followed this demo here... http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnails-pager-method-1

**THE CODE**

```
$(function() {

    // assign the slider to a variable
    var slider = $('#banner-slider').bxSlider({
        controls: false,
        mode: 'vertical',
        auto: true
    });

    // assign a click event to the external thumbnails
    $('.banner-pager a').click(function() {
        var thumbIndex = $('..banner-pager a').index(this);
        // call the "goToSlide" public function
        slider.goToSlide(thumbIndex);

        // remove all active classes
        $('.banner-pager a').removeClass('pager-active');
        // assisgn "pager-active" to clicked thumb
        $(this).addClass('pager-active');
        // very important! you must kill the links default behavior
        return false;
    });

    // assign "pager-active" class to the first thumb
    $('.banner-pager a:first').addClass('pager-active');

});
```

Any help would most awesome! Or if you can suggest a more versatile jQuery plugin then great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

with the new version the problem will be solved.
we can use :

```
pagerCustom: $('.banner-pager')
```

example page from plugin site here is the example [Thumbnail pager - method 1](http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-1)

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NXzcx/115/) is your example

Answer (score 0):

There is a callback function

```
onAfterSlide: function(currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject){  
    $('.banner-pager a.pager-active').removeClass('pager-active').next().addClass('pager-active');  
}
```

This should solve the problem of automatic toggling of class pager-active. Also after each click you'll have to start the slideshow again to solve the autoplay problem using

```
slider.reloadShow();
```

inside the click handler only.

Comment: Big thanks @tea_totaler - this seems to work pretty good, though it seems to only run through one cycle once? See what I've done http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/NXzcx/16/ - Thanks, josh

Comment: It seems to confuse itself a bit when you click on an pager.

Comment: I can't seem to get your answer to work? Could you possibly help me by adding it a jsfiddle? This is my attempt but does not seem to work correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/NXzcx/16/ Thanks

Comment: It gets messed up when you make a click only because your styles for background color are inline and somehow js fiddle screws them up.

I'm working on the other problem.

Comment: Oh yeah don't worry about the color/style issue - its just the other problem. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the version you're using in your fiddle is a bit old.  It has some problems with `onSlideAfter`:

http://jsfiddle.net/NXzcx/101/

But in that same fiddle I used the `startShow` method to restart the show after you manually select a slide.  Here's the example that shows them using onSlideAfter, I'd recommend just using that same version they have linked on this page: http://bxslider.com/examples/callback-api

Answer (score 0):

## Q

> *"...but it does not seem to add the .page-active class to current pager?"*

## A

bxSlider actually has a built-in class called `.active` that jumps to the current link in a pager. Open Devtools in your browser <kbd>F12</kbd> and find the HTML source of the pager. Whenever you transition to another slide you should see the `.active` class moving to the current index position among the links of the pager. ***If you don't see it and you have a custom pager***, then go read the ***bxPager Section*** at the bottom of this post

---

## Q

> *" ...and when you select the pager, it does not continue to automatically play?"*

## A

[**Enhancement:** Maintain auto display of slides after a manual selection #594](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4#version-424)

---

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/NXzcx/275/)

### Demo

---

```js
$(function() {
  var slider = $('.banner-slider').bxSlider({
    controls: false,
    mode: 'vertical',
    auto: true,
    pause: 5000,
    autoHover: true,
    pagerCustom: '.banner-pager',
    wrapperClass: '.banner-wrap'
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

#banner-main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner-nav {
  max-width: 260px;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #cccccc;
  position: absolute;
}

.banner-pager a {
  width: 220px;
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 25px 12px 0;
}

.banner-pager a.active,
.banner-pager a:hover {
  background: #e5e5e5;
}

.banner-wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  padding-left: 260px;
}

.banner-slide {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 720px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<main id="banner-main">
  <section class="banner-nav">
    <nav class="banner-pager">
      <a data-slide-index='0' href="#/">Dubery Wotsit</a>
      <a data-slide-index='1' href="#/">Laterz on a'menjey</a>
      <a data-slide-index='2' href="#/">Joben</a>
      <a data-slide-index='3' href="#/">Tukka Tukka</a>
      <a data-slide-index='4' href="#/">Horse Hair Duvet</a>
      <a data-slide-index='5' href="#/">FML</a>
      <a data-slide-index='6' href="#/">Balls Deep</a>
    </nav>
  </section>

  <section class="banner-wrap">
    <ul class="banner-slider">
      <li class="banner-slide" style="background: #FF0000;">
        <h3>Dubery Wotsit</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="banner-slide" style="background: #FF8000;">
        <h3>Laterz on a'menjey</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="banner-slide" style="background: #FFFF00;">
        <h3>Joben</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="banner-slide" style="background: #80FF00;">
        <h3>Tukka Tukka</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="banner-slide" style="background: #00FF00;">
        <h3>Horse Hair Duvet</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="banner-slide" style="background: #00FF80;">
        <h3>FML</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="banner-slide" style="background: #00FFFF;">
        <h3>Balls Deep</h3>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</main>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
```

---

### bxPager

---

1. Add the following **Option** to **`bxSlider()`**:

   ```
   var bx = $("ul.bx").bxSlider({
     pagerCustom: ".bxNav"
   });
   ```
2. Next create the HTML layout. The common tags used are `<ul>`, `<li>`, and of course `<div>`. I prefer using `<nav>` and `<a>`.

   ```
    <nav class="bxNav">
      <a href="#/" class="active">1</a>
      <a href="#/">2</a> 
      <a href="#/">3</a>
   </nav>
   ```
3. Now each pager link needs a `data-*` attribute:

   ```
    <nav class="bxNav">
      <a href="#/" class="active" data-slide-index="0">1</a>
      <a href="#/" data-slide-index="1">2</a> 
      <a href="#/" data-slide-index="2">3</a>
   </nav>
   ```
4. Finally, we can add `.active` class to the CSS.

   ```
   .active {
     background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     color: gold
   }
   ```